# How can I make a list with itemize in a cell of table?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to make this table:

[image]

But I haven't found the possibility to include a list in a cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use itemize in all column types which allow linebreaks, e.g. in a p column of fixed with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|}
\hline
abc & \begin{itemize}[left=0pt,topsep=0pt]
\item abc
\item def
\end{itemize}\nointerlineskip\\
\hline
abc & abc\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```